# Difference between "kinds of books", "kinds of book", "kind of books"

Tags: differences, nouns, grammatical-number

I want to know the difference between the usage of "kinds of books", "kinds of book", and "kind of books".

Comment: can't we always use "kinds of", when talking about countable nouns?

Answer (score 3):

"Kinds of books" refers to multiple kinds and multiple books. "Kind of books" refers to a single kind of book of which there are multiple examples.

Comment: You need a source to defend this view, which may not be strictly wrong but would mark the writer as mediocre.

Answer (score 2):

In Garner's Modern English Usage (3rd ed.), Garner writes:

> **these kind of; these type of; these sort of.** These are illogical forms
>   that, in a bolder day, would have been termed illiteracies. Today they merely
>   brand the speaker or writer as slovenly. ... Of course, it’s perfectly 
>   acceptable to write *these kinds* or *these types* or *these sorts.*

*These* is plural, so what follows must be plural; *of books* is not necessary for the phrase to make sense. Because a sentence such as "These sorts are up to no good" is perfectly grammatical (albeit a bit old-fashioned sounding), it's clear that both words should be singular or both should be plural.