# Types of (plural) or types of (singular)?

Tags: grammatical-number

Could anyone help me with this sentence, please?

> Weddings and graduations are two types of _______________. (ceremony or ceremonies?)

And also, could anyone explain to me when to use types of (plural) and types of (singular)? e.g.

- types of tables or types of table
- there are different types of dog(s)

Should it be *dogs* because we use *are*? Or is *are + types* instead of *are + dogs*?

Thank you!

Comment: Under “kinds of” there are many similar questions, e.g., https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16915/difference-between-kinds-of-books-kinds-of-book-kind-of-books.

Comment: And what about ceremony?

Comment: plural: ceremonies.

Comment: This often comes up. See the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox which states "W. V. O. Quine (1962) distinguished between three classes of paradoxes:". Should that have been " ... paradox"?